# Starting D-Bus Service using Golang

Tags: go, dbus

I'm now working on call and start a systemd service (mine just calls a shell script) using D-Bus API for golang.

I made a D-Bus service in /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.hello.service

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.hello
Exec=/bin/false
User=root
SystemdService=hello.service
```

And a systemd service in /lib/systemd/system/hello.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.freedesktop.hello
ExecStart=/opt/hello.sh
```

I'm trying to acheive the same result of code below, which worked.

```
sudo gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.hello --object-path /org/freedesktop/hello --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

However I keep getting the error in Golang,

```
The name org.freedesktop.hello was not provided by any .service files
```

My code for now is

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/godbus/dbus"
    "os"
    "github.com/godbus/dbus/introspect"
)

func main() {
    conn, error1 := dbus.SessionBus()
    if error1 != nil {
        panic(error1)
    }
    node, err2 := introspect.Call(conn.Object("org.freedesktop.hello", "/org/freedesktop/hello"))
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(node, "", "   ")
    os.Stdout.Write(data)
}
```

There aren't so many info about this stuff, so I want to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: The errors message seems coming from systemd. Did you run "systemctl daemon-reload” after adding the .service files?

Comment: Yes, I did reload daemon but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo gdbus call --system ...
```

That's on the system bus.

```
...
conn, error1 := dbus.SessionBus()
...
```

And this is on the session bus.

Try to use something like `dbus.SystemBus()`.

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks a lot! Hope this helps other guys facing similar problem.